# Would I need to go thru Immigration in Zurich to connect to Kyiv? SwissAir entire trip

Tags: customs-and-immigration, zurich

Flying from Spain to Ukraine, transiting (1 hr) in Zurich. Would I need to go thru Immigration in Zurich to connect to Kyiv? SwissAir entire trip.

Answer (score 9):

The word “immigration” seems to be creating a lot of confusion so here is a detailed description of what should happen during your trip:

1. When leaving Spain, there shouldn't be any police check, the airline may or may not check your ID for different purposes.
2. When you land in Zurich, there shouldn't be any systematic check (although some spot checks are always possible, including enforcement of Covid-related entry rules when relevant). You would therefore enter Switzerland and be able to exit the airport without going through any formal immigration check.
3. When leaving Zurich, you have to go through a Schengen exit check performed by the Swiss customs (*Administration fédérale des douanes* / *Eidgenössische Zollverwaltung*) or possibly the local police. That's the only “immigration” check in this part of the trip that is mandatory and systematic.

Comment: I expect the signage at ZRH would say "*Eidgenössische Zollverwaltung*", not "*Administration fédérale des douanes*".

Comment: Do you know if this changes if the OP is not a Schengen national? There are Schengen visas with limited territorial and/or multiple entry validity.

Comment: The Schengen entry and exit check is not perfomed by customs at ZRH, but by the Zurich Cantonal Police. Which is why I make the distinction.

Comment: @KristvanBesien No federal agents of any kind?

Comment: @ToivoSäwén I would expect it to be in three languages but it's a long time since I have been there (not been at Zurich since the border police has been reorganised). I just naturally expressed it in the language I know best, wasn't necessarily referring to the signage. I will add the language.

Comment: @relaxed: Switzerland doesn’t really have a federal police…

Comment: @KristvanBesien No but it has a border force dedicated to this and recently merged with customs, which is why I mentioned them. Like I said in my earlier comment, it's been some time since I last went through Zurich airport but I have seen federal agents at Basel airport, at Geneva airport, on trains, etc. (sometimes on train you would get three checks: customs, border guards *and* cantonal police).

Comment: @relaxed: The Federal Border Force is however not responsible for ZRH. That is entirely the domain of the Zürich Cantonal Police. They do both security and passport checks.

Comment: @KristvanBesien Well that was my question… Do you have any idea since when that is or more details on this? I know they had an office at the airport way back and it's difficult to find definitive info now that the border force is merged with customs.

Answer (score 4):

Both Spain and Switzerland are part of the Schengen area. So you will not have to go through passport control (immigration) in Spain, but will do so in Zürich, where you will be leaving the Schengen area.

Comment: In this case it’s actually exit checks rather than immigration. OP will not be entering Switzerland, they are already in the Schengen Area.

Comment: @jcaron the traveler won't be clearing immigration controls in Switzerland, but will certainly enter Switzerland.  How else would it be possible to get to the Swiss exit controls?

Comment: "Immigration" is shorthand for "those government officials that check your passport  and verify that you are in compliance with immigration rules". This is a police/internal order function. This is to distinguish it from customs, which is mostly a taxation/financial matter. 
You pass immigration both when you enter, and when you leave the Schengen area. In this case in Zürich.